# Button Image Resources in EXE/DLL's - Storage and Extraction

Tags: c++, mfc, embedded-resource

I am curious how to extract button image resources from an EXE? I just finished working through Ivor Horton's C++ 2013 book where he has an MFC application called Sketcher that contains button image resources created in Visual Studio. Curious as to how they are stored in the exe, I have tried a multitude of freeware "Icon Extraction" programs. Seems they only grab the main application icon, not the button image resources.

So my question is, how are button image resources stored in an EXE (or DLL)? Is it different for a .NET application vs. compiled native code?

Thanks.

JJD

Comment: They are not icons.  Easiest way is to use Visual Studio.  Use File > Open > File and select the executable file.  Shows the unmanaged resource editor.  Right click > Export to steal the art work.  Sure, .NET does it very differently, a decent decompiler can show them from the manifest resource stream.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Unless you have a specific programming question, you'll find better help elsewhere. I can't recommend a resource for this type of question, though.